# Making vars() defined variables global in a function

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I am running multiple scenarios for my experiment, which requires me to dynamically change the variable names depending upon the `Scenario` and `Class`. For that, I have got a few lines of working code, where changing simulations (i.e., `Scenario` and `Class`) changes the variable names. However, this code needs to be called everytime after I define my experiment. Code below:

```
# Funtion
def Moisture_transport(Scenario, Class, delta_crop):
    """ (unrelated to this question) """
    return Class_direct, Class_sum_cmr

""" Define the Scenario and Class """ 
Scenario = 2; Class = 1; delta_crop = True # Assign the Scenario, Class and delta_crop 

## Few lines of code that needs to run every time without any change
if delta_crop == False:
    vars()['Moisture_direct_Scenario_'+str(Scenario)+'_Class_'+str(Class)], vars()['Moisture_with_CMR_Scenario_'+str(Scenario)+'_Class_'+str(Class)] = Moisture_transport(Scenario, Class, delta_crop)
else:
    vars()['Moisture_direct_Scenario_'+str(Scenario)+'_Class_'+str(Class)+'_deltacrop'], vars()['Moisture_with_CMR_Scenario_'+str(Scenario)+'_Class_'+str(Class)+'_deltacrop'] = Moisture_transport(Scenario, Class, delta_crop)
```

Does any one know how to make `vars()['variable_name']` global in the function `Moisture_transport`?

Comment: Difficult to see why you would use vars() when you can just use a dict directly.

Comment: @jwal: Sorry, I am not quite efficient working with `dict = {}`. Also the output from the function is not always `numpy` arrays, but `xarrays` as well.  If you have a solution on how to work this out, I would be grateful.

Comment: I had to search vars() and locals() to work out what you were doing, sufficiently obscure that they did not feel pythonic. ```result = {}``` and ```result[f"{vars} {morevars}"] = <result>``` would be how I'd start.

Comment: Thank you very much. True, using the dictionary is more efficient. I have now added an answer below. If you think it seems correct, do upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be simpler still. There is some cost to handling a key so I'd not make them excessively long. Please note the `global`, where it is and is not used.

```
Moisture_variables = {}

def Moisture_transport(Scenario, Class, delta_crop):
    global Moisture_variables
    """ (unrelated to this question) """
    #return Class_direct, Class_sum_cmr
    Moisture_variables[f"{Scenario} {Class} {delta_crop}"] = (Class_direct, Class_sum_cmr)
```

You can also sub-dictionary the results although this creates a bit of overhead to checking if sub-dictionaries exist. Note I've deliberately changed (shortened) the variables in the called function to make it clear these are in a different scope.

```
Moisture_variables = {}

def Moisture_transport(Scenario, Class, delta_crop):
    """ (unrelated to this question) """
    #return Class_direct, Class_sum_cmr
    add_Moisture_Variables(Scenario, Class, delta_crop, Class_direct, Class_sum_cmr)

def add_Moisture_variables(s, c, d, cd, cs):
    global Moisture_variables
    if s not in Moisture_variables:
        Moisture_variables[s] = {}
    if c not in Moisture_variables[s]:
        Moisture_variables[s][c] = {}
    Moisture_variables[s][c][d] = (cd, cs)
```

Yet another approach if a list works, the double bracket to append a tuple are important.

```
Moisture_variables = []

def Moisture_transport(Scenario, Class, delta_crop):
    global Moisture_variables
    """ (unrelated to this question) """
    #return Class_direct, Class_sum_cmr
    Moisture_variables.append((Scenario, Class, delta_crop, Class_direct, Class_sum_cmr))
```

The choice of which approach works best depends on how you wish to recover the data.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a dictionary is more efficient in the following case to hold all the variables as `string`, which can be called with conditions, i.e., `Scenario` or `Class`.

```
#Add a last line to the original function
def Moisture_transport(Scenario, Class, delta_crop):
    """ (unrelated to this question) """
    #return Class_direct, Class_sum_cmr
    variables_dict(Class_direct, Class_sum_cmr,delta_crop)

#Add a normal dictionary and a variable name defining funtion
Moisture_variables = {}
def variables_dict(Class_direct, Class_sum_cmr, delta_crop):
    if delta_crop == False:
        Moisture_variables['Moisture_direct_Scenario_{0}_Class_{1}'.format(Scenario,Class)] = Class_direct
        Moisture_variables['Moisture_with_CMR_Scenario_{0}_Class_{1}'.format(Scenario,Class)] = Class_sum_cmr
    else:
        Moisture_variables['Moisture_direct_Scenario_{0}_Class_{1}_deltacrop'.format(Scenario,Class)] = Class_direct
        Moisture_variables['Moisture_with_CMR_Scenario_{0}_Class_{1}_deltacrop'.format(Scenario,Class)] = Class_sum_cmr
```

After that, you can run the function `Moisture_transport()` as it is, and not worry about defining the variables outside the function, i.e., code after `## Few lines of code that needs to run every time without any change` from the original question is not needed. E.g.:

```
""" Define the Scenario and Class """ 
Scenario = 1; Class = 0; delta_crop = False 
Moisture_transport(Scenario, Class, delta_crop)
```